# How to start mapreduce job from cron on GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, mapreduce

I have mapreduce job defined in mapreduce.yaml:

```
mapreduce:
- name: JobName 
  mapper:
    input_reader: google.appengine.ext.mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    handler: handler_name
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: KindName
```

How to start it from cron? Is there some url that can run it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can start a mapreduce task from any kind of AppEngine handler using [control.py](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/control.py)

```
from mapreduce import control

mapreduce_id = control.start_map(
    "My Mapper",
    "main.my_mapper",
    "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
    {"entity_kind": "models.MyEntity"},
    shard_count=10)
```

Comment: I noticed a comment in the file that says that `start_map` is deprecated and to use `map_job.start` instead; this comment may have been added after this answer was given.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, if you look at the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) page, it shows that you set the URL in your `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce/main.py
  login: admin
```

You then can just cron it in the usual App Engine fashion, which in this example would be writing a `cron.yaml` like this:

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /mapreduce
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

Comment: This will create a cron job that fetches the mapreduce admin page once a day. It won't execute any mapreduces.